# Updating one cell when data has been entered into other cells

Tags: formulas

I want to create a worksheet where the value of two cells will fill in another cell, i.e. if cells `J4` and `K4` both have a zero in it then `D4` would automatically have a `1` entered.

Comment: It's a little unclear, what do you want - comparison of two cells?

Comment: I assume that this is excel? Please tag more appropriately or edit the question so that this is clear. It will attract more viewers if you use multiple tags

Answer (score 0):

Use AND to combine the output of multiple logical tests that all must be true.

Insert the following formula into cell d4:

```
=IF(AND(j4=0,k4=0),1,"")
```

Here I have simply compared to zero but you can use functions including nested IF or OR for more complicated scenarios. You did not specify the value that you want when either cell has a value, so I have left that as an empty string.

Comment: No! OP has zeroes (`0`) and wants the result  `1`. `ISBLANK(0)` is `False` so by your expression he will get empty string (`""`).

Comment: Good point, well then it's the other way around... I'll fix that now.